# Why am I experiencing DOMS in my legs when I'm currently not working out?

Tags: cardio, strength-training, doms

I feel Delayed Onset Muscle Soreness in my thighs, however I do not work out. The only thing I do in the gym is cardio. I do the elliptical for about 45 minutes a few times per week at a very fast speed at zero resistance, and zero incline. If the culprit is the cardio, is DOMS possible for someone doing no exercise at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes. DOMS isn't only experienced after focusing on exercise, but whenever your muscles have been subjected to strenuous work which it's not accustomed to.

It's very possible that cardio is the culprit, but for someone who doesn't exercise at all, even taking a flight of stairs could cause DOMS.

It's sometimes hard to pinpoint the exact reason, given the delayed reaction. It's easy to think it might have been the cardio, when in fact, it could have been something else that you didn't even think about, and have already forgotten.